# Trouble compiling an example from the LaTeX Graphics Companion

Tags: diagrams

I've been trying to compile code samples from the wonderful *The LaTeX Graphics Companion. Second Edition, by Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, Sebastian Rahtz, Denis Roegel HerbertVoB
IT Addison*, but I've run into trouble.

Here is an example of code I'm trying to compile (page 45):

```
\usepackage{multido , pict2e}
\begin{picture} (11S,60) (-45,-30)
\ linethickness {1.6pt}
\multido{\ iA=-30+10,\ iB=15+ 5 } { S }
{ \put (\ iA ,O) {\ circle{\ } } }
\put ( 50 , 0 ) { \ c ir c l e * {50
\ end{picture}
```

Is there a special package to run that kind of example?

Comment: Is this exactly what you tried to compile without any additions?

Comment: You copy/past from pdf and the result is the mess.

Comment: @ppr True, but not very helpful...

Comment: I think Second edition examples are not available on ctan.org. [Examples from First Edition of "The LaTeX Graphics Companion"](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/examples/lgc/) are available. For more examples look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=latex-books

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

The companion style is to give an indication of the packages needed without putting the full `\documentclass` code in every time, for reasons of space. Then the body of your example has been scrambled probably through some font encoding mismatch. I don't have the original to hand but guessing from what you posted, I suspect you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido , pict2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{picture} (115,60) (-45,-30)
\linethickness{1.6pt}
\multido{\iA=-30+10,\iB=15+ 5}{5}
{\put (\iA ,0){\circle{\iB}}}
\put (50,0) {\circle*{50}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: David,Thanks. That's right. Thank you. Solved my problem